Wide format data by pasting two sets of variables into one in R
I've tried to wide-format my DATA into my Desired_output using:
pivot_wider(DATA, names_from = Year, values_from = c(Type, Language))
without success. Is there a way to achieve my Desired_output?
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID District       Type Year Language
1 GreshamBarlow   5F  1617   Spanish
1 GreshamBarlow   5F  1718   Spanish
2 JeffersonCounty 5F  1617   English
2 JeffersonCounty 5F  1718   English")


Desired_output <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID District        1617             1718 
1  GreshamBarlow   5F_Spanish       5F_Spanish
2  JeffersonCounty 5F_English       5F_English")


DATA %>% 
   unite(Type, Type, Language) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Type)

# A tibble: 2 × 4
     ID District        `1617`     `1718`    
  <int> <chr>           <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 GreshamBarlow   5F_Spanish 5F_Spanish
2     2 JeffersonCounty 5F_English 5F_English


You can create the combined variable before doing the pivot_wider() and it should give your required result
Desired_output <- DATA %>%
    transmute(ID, District, Year, newvar = paste(Type, Language, sep="_")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = newvar)

Desired_output
#   ID        District     `1617`     `1718`
# 1  1   GreshamBarlow 5F_Spanish 5F_Spanish
# 2  2 JeffersonCounty 5F_English 5F_English

